# How do I remove a directory inside container with JIB?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers, jib

If it is a docker file, I want to remove the directory by executing the following command.

```
RUN rm /usr/bin/wget
```

How can I do it? any help is appreciated

Comment: You might be able to do it by creating your own image without wget and then telling JIB to use that image as the base image for your build. https://cloud.google.com/java/getting-started/jib#base-image
Or you could set up a `docker build` step after your JIB build that removes wget.

Comment: in linux for removing folders you have tu use switch -r, so your command will be `RUN rm -rf /folder/to/be/removed`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First thing to emphasize**: in `Dockerfile`, `RUN rm /usr/bin/wget` *doesn't physically remove the file*. Files and directories in previous layers will physically stay there forever. So, if you are trying to remove a file with sensitive information using `rm`, it's not going to work. As an example, recently, this oversight has led to a high-profile [security breach](https://about.codecov.io/apr-2021-post-mortem/) in Codecov.

> **Docker Layer Attacks**: Publicly distributed Docker images should be either squashed or multistage such that intermediate layers that contain sensitive information are excluded from the final build.

What happens is, `RUN rm /usr/bin/wget` creates another layer that contains a "whiteout" file `/usr/bin/.wh.wget`, and this new layer sits on top of all previous layers. Then at runtime, it's just that container runtimes will hide the file and you will not see it. However, if you download the image and inspect each layer, you will be able to see and extract both `/usr/bin/wget` and `/usr/bin/.wh.wget` files. So, yes, doing `rm` later doesn't reduce the size of the image at all. (BTW, each `RUN` in `Dockerfile` creates a new layer at the end. So, for example, if you remove files within the same `RUN` like `RUN touch /foo && rm /foo`, you will not leave `/foo` in the final image.)

Therefore, with Jib, if the file or directory you want to "delete" is coming from a base image, what you can do is to create a new whiteout file for it. Jib has the [`<extraDirectories>` feature](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin#adding-arbitrary-files-to-the-image) to copy arbitrary files into an image. So, for example, since `<project root>/src/main/jib` is the default extra directory, you can create an empty `src/main/jib/usr/bin/.wh.wget`, which will be coped into `/usr/bin/.wh.wget` in an image.

And of course, if you really want to physically remove the file that comes from the base image, the only option is to rebuild your base image so that it doesn't contain `/usr/bin/wget`.

For completeness: if the file or directory you want to remove is not from your base image but from Jib, you can use the Jib Layer-Filter extension ([Maven](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib-extensions/tree/master/first-party/jib-layer-filter-extension-maven)/[Gradle](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib-extensions/tree/master/first-party/jib-layer-filter-extension-gradle)). (This is app-layer filtering and doesn't involve whiteout files.) However, normally there will be no reason to remove files put by Jib.